# Passing data from hidden field to Razor to update database

Tags: javascript, razor

Trying to grab string from hidden field for sql update purpose.

What I'm doing overall is the following...

Retrieving a record set of locations (latitude+longitude) from Azure SQL

Plotting these coordinates on a Google Map using their Javascript API

Thru the listener event, I want to update the database with the new coordinates when user moves marker. Struggling with this last bit.

Below is my code.... I'm new to Razor and only learning the syntax. Found out that I can pass data from Razor C# to Javascript... but (maybe) not the other way around? Therefore storing the sql update query in a hidden field - and trying to retrieve this in the listener event.

How do I go about this? Not using Entity Framework (too steep of a learning curve for me right now).

Help greatly appreciated, Thank you.

```
@page
@model GoogleMapsPage.Pages.Google_MapsModel
@using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div><input type="hidden" id="secretfield" /></div>
        <div id="map"></div>

        <script>

            const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

            let functionality = params.get('f');
            let username = params.get('username');

            var title;
            var draggable;
            draggable = false;

            switch (functionality.toUpperCase()) {
                case "GEO":
                    title = "Flyt beholder, " + username;
                    draggable = true;
                    break;
                case "NEAREST":
                    title = "Nærmeste beholder(e), " + username;
                    break;
                case "ROUTE":
                    title = "Ruter i nærheden, " + username;
                    break;
                default:
                    title = "Fejl!";
                    break;
            }

            var RenoData = [];

            @{
                var myConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
                var connSQL = myConfig.GetConnectionString("AzureSQL");
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connSQL);
                string selQuery = "select KeyID, cast(latitude as varchar) as Latitude, cast(longitude as varchar) as Longitude, address, contentstring, color from dbo.map where username = '" + Request.Query["username"].ToString().ToLower() + "';";

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand selCmd = new SqlCommand(selQuery, conn);
                SqlDataReader rdr = selCmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    @while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        @:RenoData.push({ KeyID: @rdr["KeyID"].ToString(), lat: 1 * (@rdr["Latitude"]), lng: 1 * (@rdr["Longitude"]) });
                    }
                }

                rdr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            };

            var map;

            async function initMap() {

                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: { lat: RenoData[0].lat, lng: RenoData[0].lng },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT }
                });

                var location;
                var pos;

                const positions = [];

                // Iterate thru records
                for (var i = 0; i < RenoData.length; i++) 
                {
                    // Set markers regardless
                    addMarker(RenoData[i], map);

                    // Data for polygon
                    pos = { lat: RenoData[i].lat, lng: RenoData[i].lng };
                    positions.push(pos);
                };

                if (functionality === 'NEAREST') {
                    const poly = new google.maps.Polygon(
                    {
                        paths: positions,
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: "#FF0000",
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        editable: true,
                        clickable: true,
                        draggable: false
                    });

                    poly.setMap(map);
                }

                // Add marker(s) to the map
                function addMarker(rd, map)
                {
                    // Add the marker at the clicked location
                    var m = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        name: rd.KeyID,
                        position: { lat: rd.lat, lng: rd.lng },
                        draggable: draggable,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        title: rd.KeyID,
                        map: map
                    });

                    m.addListener('dragend', function ()
                    {
                        var pos = m.getPosition();
                        map.setCenter(pos);
                        console.log(pos.lat);

                        var updSQL = "update dbo.maps set newlatitude = " + pos.lat() + ", newlongitude = " + pos.lng()
                        + " where 1 = 1 and keyid = " + m.name + " and username = '" + username + "';";
                        
                        document.getElementById("secretfield").innerHTML = updSQL;

                        @{
                            string updQuery = @Html.Hidden("secretfield").ToString();
                            conn.Open();
                            SqlCommand updCmd = new SqlCommand(updQuery, conn);
                            updCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                        };
                    });
                }
            }

            initMap();

        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry,drawing" async defer></script>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.Hidden("secretfield").ToString();
```

Comment: A lot of this doesn't make much sense.  There's an explicitly defined hidden `<input>` (though it's missing a `name` so wouldn't be posted in a form), but then at the end there's some weird call to `Html.Hidden("secretfield").ToString()`?  Why?  That's also included somewhere else near the end?  Also, are you defining SQL code client-side?  You ***absolutely do not*** want to do that, otherwise you'd be letting your users **write their own SQL code**, which is just inviting malicious users to break your database.

Comment: Overall it looks like you may have "bitten off more than you can chew" here.  You appear to be trying to mix server-side code and client-side code in ways that very clearly won't work, and it looks like the result of copying/pasting bits of code from various sources without any understanding of the structure of the application or of how a web application works in general.  Now is probably a good time to scrap this code and start again.  Start smaller.  Build, test, and verify one piece of functionality at a time before trying to add the next piece.